# iBeacon ,iOS13 , BGAppRefreshTask

Tags: background, core-location, ios13, operation

i need implement detecting `iBeacons` in background every for example 5 min, for this I want use new Apple framework BackgroundTask

This how I implement my operation subclass

```
import CoreLocation

class BeaconsRecord: AsyncOperation {

    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    private let clBeaconIdentityConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint
    var beacons = [CLBeacon]()

    init (locationManager: CLLocationManager, uuid: UUID) {
        self.locationManager = locationManager
        self.clBeaconIdentityConstraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: uuid)
        super.init()
    }

    override func main() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: clBeaconIdentityConstraint)
    }
}

extension BeaconsRecord: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        self.locationManager.stopRangingBeacons(satisfying: clBeaconIdentityConstraint)
        self.beacons = beacons
        self.state = .Finished
    }
}
```

if i use it from foreground it work perfect , then i trying use it from background , as it shown in wwdc presentation it doesn't work.
That i miss ?
My appdelegate implementation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager : CLLocationManager?
let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!

lazy var detectBeaconsQueue : OperationQueue = {
    var queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.name = "detectBeaconsQueue"
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    return queue
}()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    registerBackgroundTaks()
    registerLocalNotification()

    return true
}

//MARK: Register BackGround Tasks
func registerBackgroundTaks() {
    BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx", using: nil) { task in
         self.scheduleLocalNotification()
         self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
      }
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    cancelAllPendingBGTask()
    scheduleAppRefresh()
}
```

}

extension AppDelegate {

```
func cancelAllPendingBGTask() {
    BGTaskScheduler.shared.cancelAllTaskRequests()
}

func scheduleAppRefresh() {
       let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: ""xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx"")

       // Fetch no earlier than 1 minutes from now
    request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1 * 60)
       do {
          try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
       } catch {
          print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
       }
    }

func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
    // Schedule a new refresh task
    scheduleAppRefresh()

    let operation = BeaconsRecord(locationManager: locationManager!,
                                  uuid: uuid)

    task.expirationHandler = {
        operation.cancel()
    }

    operation.completionBlock = {
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: !operation.isCancelled)
    }

    detectBeaconsQueue.addOperation(operation)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After working Beacon based projects over 2 years I can say that **there is no way to detect iBeacon in the background specifically in your scenario**.

In the iOS background, **the task will be terminated after 3 minutes** you started the task if you starting to background determination, for battery save. The only way is, while working app in beacon ranging mode, you can be called the thread every 5 minutes to determine beacon last status, without terminating the app. The screen can be closed but the app must still work. **BUT It's not a legal scenario.** Apple review team **doesn't approve your application** for protecting users' benefits.

**There is no problem with Beacon Monitoring in the background,** but you only to know if the beacon signal is still connected to the device, or not connected over 30 seconds.

You must know the difference between Monitoring and Region Scanning deeply. And if in this your scenario is not applied from ***Background Monitoring***, there is no way to determine beacon status in the background with ***Beacon Ranging***, every 5 minutes.

**For more information read it**: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203914068-Is-it-possible-to-use-beacon-ranging-in-the-background-

Comment: Maybe i miss something but Background task exactly was designed for it  , not ? Refresh Background operation give to your application until 30 seconds in background to fetch new data and update UI .In my case i fetch new data from around beacons and not some web server.